# Family sharing, some clarifications needed

Tags: itunes, icloud, family-sharing

Recently we've set up *family sharing*. Now my SO has done an in-app purchase. So far no issue. But when I told her she was a little upset that there was no way to make the payment herself. Because obviously I got to see the purchase.

**So, how can she pay for her own purchases, whenever she desires?**

[This article](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201079) suggests it is not possible, except when using iTunes store credit or vouchers.

**And will the receipts for purchases based on her iTunes store credit or vouchers also end up in my mailbox?**

After all in many families there isn't just a single parent and then kids (in this context apparently handled as subordinates). It seems like this would be based on a view on the woman as stay-home mom with the husband paying for everything?!

Answer (score 1):

She can purchase iTunes gift cards then redeem them in your account. Yes, you will still see the transaction but it won't be charged to your credit card.